# Revision reopen review queue shows "No changes to display" for a revision with changes

Tags: bug, review-queues, revision-history, vote-to-reopen

On the revision tab for [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/4923858), it shows the edit comment (*added 12 characters in body*) but not the actual revision (*No changes to display*). Looking at the [actual revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23910771/revisions), it's obvious there was a change in that edit (replacing values on a single line).

[image: Bugged freehand circles]

I can reproduce it by going directly to that first link on Chrome (where I'm logged in) and on IE8 (where I am not).

Chrome is running version 35.0.1916.114 m.

IE8 is running version 8.0.7601.17514, and was launched fresh to reproduce this issue (it was not open when this began).

For other reviews (like [this old one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/4923859)), I see the revision markup (on both browsers). I also see the revision markup on the most recent review I saw (seconds ago).

[image: Not bugged freehand circles]

Why is that specific review not displaying the most recent revision's markup?

Comment: +1, I was feeling like we left all the freehand red circles behind on Meta.SE

Comment: Looks like bug is still present. [Here's a review I just did today that demonstrates it](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/8826354). I'm on Chrome 43.0.2357.134 m.

Comment: Another one from today: https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/17701590

Comment: Still a thing: https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/18739192